# Определение серверная/десктопная версия ОС

Tags: python

Необходимо определить в скрипте `Python`, где она запускается: на сервере или десктоп версии ОС.

К примеру `Ubuntu Server` или `Desktop`.

В модуле platform смотрел не нашел. Есть цивилизованный способ?

Comment: Зачем это может быть нужно?

Comment: В контроле наличия пакетов и позволяет переключать программы в ГУИ режим на десктопной машине

Comment: Сервер - это просто десктоп без иксов, а десктоп - это просто сервер с иксами, и понять кто где невозможно, не?

Comment: Возможно гдето прописывается дистр полностью например Ubuntu Desktop 12.04.2 LTS i386. Тогда косвенно по наличию слова Desktop или Server можно определить.

Comment: А если пользователь захочет запустить вашу программу в ГУИ режиме на сервере? :)

Comment: А пользователь не должен этого делать )) Я и хочу ему это запретить ))

Comment: связанный вопрос имеет хороший ответ: [How to check if Ubuntu Desktop or Server is installed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/12562/3712) (вопрос имеет мало смысла, если не конкретизировать требования -- перенесите всю необходимую для ответа информацию из комментариев в сам вопрос. Может вам просто `$DISPLAY` проверить нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Точно не определить но можно посмотреть установленные отличительные пакеты.

Например посмотреть установлен ли ubuntu-desktop

```
package_name = "ubuntu-desktop"

def isPackageInstalled(package_name):
    apt_pkg.init_config()
    apt_pkg.init_system()
    return apt_pkg.Cache()[package_name].current_state == apt_pkg.CURSTATE_INSTALLED
```

Также посмотри наличие других отличительных пакетов